# error while launching ekf_template.launch in ros noetic

Tags: c++, ros

I just installed `robot_localization` package then build it, now I'm trying to launch `ekf_template.launch` it throws error as

```
"[ WARN] [1687168554.288131694]: X acceleration is being measured from IMU; X velocity control input is disabled"
```

Everything is connected properly in turtlebot3 burger and remote pc and master were connected to ROS core but still I get this error.

But it's a warning, it got stuck after this I attach screenshot of this

It is calibrated correctly, what can I do to solve this issue, can you guys please help me with this?

[image]

These are the steps:

1. `cd ~/catkin_ws/src`
2. `git clone https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization.git`
3. `cd ~/catkin_ws`
4. `catkin_make_isolated`
5. `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`
6. `roslaunch robot_localization ekf_template.launch`

This is the error I get:

```
[ WARN] [1687168554.288131694]: X acceleration is being measured from IMU; X velocity control input is disabled
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't think the warning you are pasting has nothing to do with the localisation not working. Do you run the robot drivers launch file before running the localisation?

Comment: yes now i cleared that error by modify control_config's  x velocity as false, now error has gone but new error arrived  - [ WARN] [1690463575.419175041, 1066.884000000]: Failed to meet update rate! Took 1066.8840000000000146 please help me